# Pretty form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am currently validating my forms using an alert system from jquery.  Just with this following code:

```
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.getElementById('inf_field_FirstName').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('inf_field_Email').value;
    if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name") {
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.getElementById('inf_field_Email').value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, I would like this to be a cooler looking validation rather than just having a popup telling a user to go back and complete the form again.

I stumbled across this form here: http://lewishowes.com/ at the 'start living the dream now' part.  Whenever you don't type something in some text pops up in a box below the field telling you how you didn't fill out the form correctly.

How can a method like this be achieved?

Comment: you should try validation engine, it can be smart solution for you https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular example, there is actually no libraries or cool work done, he simply uses built in HTML5 validation methods. On the email field, for example, he does not do `type="text"` but instead `type="email"`. That means that when the form tries to be submitted, the browser will automatically check to make sure it is valid. There are also more advanced, custom, methods, I believe, but using an `email` type on the `input` tag is the first step, and is often enough for simple cases. You also use `required` attribute to make a field required. And instead of leaving just `First Name` as the default value for the first name field, use the `placeholder` attribute. e.g:

```
<input type="text" id="inf_field_FirstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="email" id="inf_field_Email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/UdJ4Z/1/
Note that you will get an error when submitting the form because there is nothing on the server side to handle the form. However, you will be able to see the messages when you enter invalid text

Note that you should also use standard JavaScript or server-side validation, as this has limited browser support. If user input is going to do something on the server that could be abused, MAKE SURE you have server-side validation, or somebody will hack your website.

Comment: good warnings...  And I always wonder about who actually has the time of day to sit around and hack random websites just for the hell of it.

Comment: sometimes there's more than "just for the hell of it". They could use SQL injection to mess up a database which might be containing user information, which they could sell or use directly. And users don't like that.

Comment: Wow, I truly had no idea HTML5 offered such an easy way to use form validation.  Thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: I know, HTML5 is pretty powerful! Here are some even more powerful ways to use it with customized regexes and custom messages/pictures: http://developer.nokia.com/Blogs/Code/2012/11/21/creating-a-custom-html5-form-validation/

Comment: @user1953681 - even though HTML5 has some pretty awesome features, just remember that not every browser supports it and you should try to make the site still functional for those people.

Comment: That's another reason to have server-side validation, apart from just security